# Show view on button event in Sencha Architect

Tags: extjs, sencha-architect

I have just started using Sencha Architect, and I have problems doing even the simplest of things. I'm trying to go to the next view, when a button is clicked. The code I have so far makes an alert when the button is clicked.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',

    config: {
        layout: {
            align: 'center',
            type: 'vbox'
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'fieldset',
                width: 500,
                title: 'Login',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'selectfield',
                        label: 'Vælg bil',
                        store: 'cars'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'passwordfield',
                        label: 'Adgangskode'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                        label: 'Husk mig'
                    },
                    {
                        xtype: 'button',
                        handler: function(button, event) {
                            alert("foo");
                        },
                        text: 'Log ind'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }

});
```

What should go instead of the alert, to add a new view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this one to open up a view with id "sampleview":

```
if(Ext.getCmp('sampleview'))
{
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('sampleview'));
}
else 
{
    var sample = Ext.create('App.view.SampleView');
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(sample);
}
```

Comment: I can't get this to work. I have given my container the id 'sampleview', but nothing happens when the event fires. Not even an error in the console. My project is at https://github.com/danielsvane/senchaviewtest. Could you maybe take a look? Thanks.

Comment: Nevermind, you were right, I was just not using it correctly. Why is it necessary to create the view on the event? Is there a way to create it before, and just use 'Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('sampleview'));'?

Comment: I checked your code but as I see you only used one line of the above code. You can simply write:

    `var sample = Ext.create('App.view.SampleView');
    Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(sample);`

instead of:

    `Ext.Viewport.setActiveItem(Ext.getCmp('sampleview'));`

I wrote the above if-condition just to avoid multiple creation of the view.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that when looking at the code again. I thought the else clause would just create an empty view. Can you recommend any resources for Sencha Architect? There doesn't seem to be much out there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! Actually it is a very new tool so it's not documented well yet. So you should make do with the existing documents on [http://docs.sencha.com] for now.